# show default text inside a textbox before form submit and user entered data after form submit

Tags: php, forms, textbox, echo

I have textbox in my html form to enter email ID. I am showing a default text `Enter Your Email ID here` before user click inside the textbox and my code is

```
<input class="textbox" type="text" id="emailbox" name="emailbox" value="Enter Your Email ID here" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" />
```

Now Once I submit the form instead of the default text `Enter Your Email ID here` I need to show user entered email ID inside the textbox.

I am able to show user entered data on a normal textbox after form submit using below code

```
<input  class="textbox" id="mem_count" name="mem_count" type="text"  value="<?php if(isset($_POST['mem_count'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['mem_count']); }?>" />
```

How can I keep the same data on my email textbox which has a default text ?

Comment: You can do this using javascript easily , but it can be done with php as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding an else statement on the conditional would do it, if no data then echo default text

```
<input  class="textbox" id="mem_count" name="mem_count" type="text"  value="<?php if(isset($_POST['mem_count'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['mem_count']); } else { echo "Enter Your Email ID here";}?>"  placeholder="Enter Your Email ID here" onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter Your Email ID here')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Enter Your Email ID here';" />
```

Comment: : This working but, only issue I see is whenever I click inside the textbox, it is not removing the default text `Enter Your Email ID here' I was able to do that using my initial code

Answer (score 0):

Initialization of input's value :

```
<?php
    $value=(isset($_POST['mem_count'])) ? htmlentities ($_POST['mem_count']) :"Enter Your Email ID here";    
?>
```

**HTML**:

```
<input  class="textbox" id="mem_count" name="mem_count" type="text"  value="<?php echo $value ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I like ravenlp's solution, and using the posted value might be more useful in situations where a login failed, perhaps.

```
<input value="<?php echo ((@$_POST['emailbox']) ?: 'Enter Your Email ID here') ?>" class="textbox" type="text" id="emailbox" name="emailbox" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really use the HTML attribute `placeholder` as it will auto show the place holder when the field is empty.

```
<input class="textbox" type="text" id="emailbox" name="emailbox" value="<? $_POST['mem_count'] ?>" placeholder="Enter Your Email ID here" />
```

This also removes the need to have JavaScript enabled to use the form field without having to manually clear it out. I've personally tested it in IE7+, and I read that it's supported in Chrome/Safari 4.0+ and Firefox 3.7+.